# Linq query for Get Data within Date in .net core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I wanted to select data within the dates given using linq query (.net core).

The entity is

`public List<Slots> Dates { get; set; }`

and

```
public class Slots
{
   public string SlotName { get; set; }
   public DateTime SlotDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is the scenario. I want to select all data within dates from `Dates` but I need to match the date with `SlotDate`.

I tried

```
IEnumerable<Programs> programs = await _programRepository.GetAllAsync(p => p.Dates.Select(d => d.SlotDate >= startDate && d.SlotDate<=endDate));
```

Comment: `I tried` And what happened?

Comment: @mjwills Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<domain.Entity.Slots>' to 'bool'

Comment: Can you show us `GetAllAsync`?

Comment: @mjwills You can replace it with where. And we can add ToListAsync at last.

Comment: What is the relationship between 'Program' and Slots? Can you post the models?

Comment: You should tell us what you actually wants result. According to your description, it seems that you want to get entity which Dates property's SlotDate is between the startDate and endDate. If this is your requirement, you should try this `Where(x => x.Dates.Select(x => x.SlotDate <= DateTime.Now).Single())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq will handle the DateTimes just fine, you can use standard greater-than/less-than operators. Very basic example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
        
public class Slots
{
   public string SlotName { get; set; }
   public DateTime SlotDate { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Slots> Dates = new List<Slots>();
        Dates.Add(new Slots()
        {
            SlotName = "Test1",
            SlotDate = DateTime.Now
        });
        Dates.Add(new Slots()
        {
            SlotName = "Test2",
            SlotDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5)
        });
                      
        var selection = Dates.Where(s => s.SlotDate > DateTime.Now).Single();
        
        Console.WriteLine(selection.SlotName);
    }
}
```

[Try it out here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7VfUIo). Obviously you won't be using DateTime.Now, but the simple 'Where' line is all you'll need. If you want to find values between two dates, just add an `&&` and another condition.

This is just getting a `.Single()` value from the selection. If you want to find multiple values, use `.ToList()` - the value you get back will be a list that you can handle like any other list.

Comment: Yes thats fine but but I wanted to use repository as well. `IEnumerable<Programs> programs = await _programRepository.GetAllAsync(p => p.Dates.Select(d => d.SlotDate >= startDate && d.SlotDate<=endDate));` like this.